# Aptana Studio 3 wont open on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, aptana, macos-sierra, aptana3

I'm having a problem opening Aptana Studio 3.6.1 on my 2012 Macbook Pro.  I used to have OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) and it worked fine when it was on there, but when I recently updated to Sierra 10.12.6, it stopped working.

I received the first error message (attached below; Aptana Error Message 1) the first few times after the update, and after deleting and re-downloading it *twice*, I got the second error message that was just the usual "Ignore, Report, Reopen" message.

[Aptana Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7bGd.png)

[Aptana Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzBM1.png)

I'm new to programming in general, so I have no idea what would be causing all this, so any advice that could help me fix Aptana would be greatly appreciated.